# Push notification Implementation

Tags: iphone, push-notification

How to implement Push notification in iPhone?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to accept some answers to your (other) questions. It will help you get answers in the future.

Comment: Have you tried searching Google? There are at least three keywords in your pseudo-question.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052645/apple-pns-push-notification-services-sample-code

Answer (score 5):

The Apple documentation on Push Notifications is very clear, with sample code:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't interested in implementing your own server solution for providing push notifications to your client, you might be interested in these solutions:

http://appnotify.com/

http://urbanairship.com/push/

Each charge a fee for push notifications sent, but they also abstract away most of the initial setup complexity and, obviously, the costs associated with maintaining one's own server/bandwidth.

If you're interested in hosting your own solution, I've had success with Apns4r, a Rails plugin: http://github.com/searls/Apns4r

Answer (score 1):

There is also an open source python Apple Push Notification server, in case you want to roll your own and don't fancy any of the options that Justin mentioned.

http://leepa.github.com/django-iphone-push/