# push notification

Tags: iphone

hi i need to implement client side APNs in iphone, please help me with sample application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085642/push-notification)

Answer (score 0):

It seems a basic request, have you already seen

[Apple.Developer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

?

I can say that there is not much code to write on the iphone client-side