# Push notification or thread with timer

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multithreading, apple-push-notifications

In my application, I'm having functionality like twitter that when you have not refreshed your screen, and if there're new messages then you get this message that "You have n new messages" and a refresh button, which on press will refresh the screen.

I'm basically fetching all the data from an xml with some url.

In case of thread, I need to call a timer after some time period which might affect the app performance.

Can anybody please suggest wheather what will be better to use push notifications or thread with timer?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just notify the user about the new data available then definitely go for Push notifications rather than pulling the information on thread with timer.

Pulling of information always consume more resources than pushing message from external sources.

Comment: Basically, I need to notify user about the availibility of new data and if there's any new data, then I need to pull that data. Does push notification service assuming the process of setting up your server and secure connection to apple server is complex? Because I'm very new to this. Can you suggest any of good tutorials that are available?

Comment: Please refer this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052645/apple-pns-push-notification-services-sample-code