# Iphone Sdk:Is it possible to use an UISwitch to enable and disable PNS(Push Notification Service)?

Tags: iphone, sdk, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uiswitch

I find some sample code about PNS,[article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052645/apple-pns-push-notification-services-sample-code)

and I also create an UISwitch to enable PNS

how to give a method to control the PNS ?

This is how I declare cell

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"PNS";
  [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
  pushNotificationSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
  [cell addSubview:pushNotificationSwitch];
  cell.accessoryView = pushNotificationSwitch;
  [(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView addTarget:self action:@selector(pushNotification:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 }


- (void)pushNotification:(id)sender{
 if (pushNotificationSwitch.on==YES) {
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)pushNotificationSwitch.superview;
  [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
 }
 else {
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)pushNotificationSwitch.superview;
  [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
 }
}
```

now I'm just use a cell's text label color change to representation  the switch is call the method

SO... can I use it to control PNS enable or not ???

Thanks for any comments and answers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all the following to work, you should have registered with Apple for Push notification services as a Notification provider.

According to user's choice of input from Switch control, you can call

> unregisterForRemoteNotifications

or

> registerForRemoteNotificationTypes

.

If user wants to unregister from Notification, this is possible by invoking [unregisterForRemoteNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications) method.

Once again if you wanted to register for the notification, you can use registerForRemoteNotificationTypes method on your Application object.

For more info you can refer this [link](http://mobworld.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/push-notifications/).

**UPDATE:**

You can call it this way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

You can use the links I have referred for more info.

Comment: I declare this two method at appdelegate.m,I still can call this at other place ?

Comment: If you are referring to "unregisterForRemoteNotifications" and "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes", these two of them can be called on your shared Application instance. I have updated the answer on how this call can be made.

Comment: Thanks ,I just figure out the PNS certification issues.I will try this now if it work's I will tell you !

Comment: may I ask why every time I turn on the switch,and go to other view,and back to the view with switch,it will become turn off ? how to record the last status I click the switch ?

Comment: Hi, You can get the state of switch when the View disappears(viewdiddisappear), and store in NSUserDefaults or in a global variable and set the Switch to stored state, when the view again appears.

Comment: I nerver try this before ,I will give it a shoot

Answer (score 2):

You can activate the PNS for your app with `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` or deactivate it with `unregisterForRemoteNotifications`.
See [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotificationTypes%3a) for more information:

Comment: How to put this into - (void)pushNotification:(id)sender ?can you give some sample code ?thx