# How to implement Apple push notification service in iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i implement Push Notification in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468327/how-can-i-implement-push-notification-in-iphone)

How to implement Apple push notification service in iphone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sry but your question shows lack of previous research

Answer (score 1):

1. Read Apple's [documentation on push notifications and how to implement them](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1).
2. Follow the documentation and you're done.
3. Come back here with specific questions if you encounter problems you can't solve on your own.