# How to implement Urban Airship for Push notification in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use urbanairship push notification. But while creating instance of UAirship, it is showing error that UAirship is undeclared.i have implemented urbanairship upto http://urbanairship.com/docs/apns_test_client.html#prerequisite and after then i do not know what should i do ? Waiting for response. Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution to this? When i add it  to my project it crashes with The Debugger has exited with status 0.
_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow called from function +[UAPush allocWithZone:] in image de Bijenkorf.

Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:

_Unwind_Resume called from function CFRunLoopRunSpecific in image CoreFoundation.

Comment: Hey just follow the steps given in this link : http://urbanairship.com/docs/apns_test_client.html  And let me know if you need any other help

Comment: Hi Devang i was able to install the framework and run it, but when i send a notification i get an error on the server saying my device token is inactive, also on the device it says application or secret key not inserted properly in the plist file.

Comment: Have you copied your Development App key and secret key into AirshipConfig.plist

Comment: Yes i have copied that, tried a million other solutions, have you got ur application set up?

Comment: Yes. I have successfully implemented Push notification. Try to upload .p12 again or check which profile you are selecting. And let me know Are you testing for adhoc ?

Comment: Yes i am trying to work with a complete new set of certs. Let me see how this goes, I am testing for developement account. Can I call you up, if that does not work, or are u on skype?

Comment: you can contact me on my gmail : devang3888@gmail.com

Comment: have you check your provisioning profile ?

Comment: Hey devang we finally managed to make it work on with the testing account, but when i change to production it gives me the "app key or secret key not set properly" error on the device. Y would that be?

Comment: @Devang let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1944/discussion-between-b-k-and-devang)

Comment: make change in your AirshipConfig -> APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD = YES and you can test this for adhoc (distribution) profile not for debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included `UAirship.h` and `UAPush.h` ?

Comment: Yes.. I have included both of this file.But its not allowing to create instance of UAirship. Do you have any sample code of urban airship push notification? And Thanks for replying ...

Comment: Have you added configurations files like : http://urbanairship.com/docs/airship_lib.html#library-airship-config-reference

Comment: I have added that. I got the error in applicationDidFinishLaunching:application that "UAPush is not declared"

Comment: If you have exactly the same code, and you have configured libraries as described in http://urbanairship.com/docs/richpush_client.html#setup-reference, you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: I'm feeling great that atleast someone is replying. I am following same steps as given by urban airship but its not working. do you have any sample code ?

Comment: I have no sample code because it's the same as the documentation...The only advice I give to you since your error is to check that the libraries are added and properly configured, and that the headers are present.

Answer (score 1):

I got something similar just now. Might not be the same problem, but there seems to be a massive bug in the UA library - a combination of careless code design, and badly written code.

Apparently ... you MUST NOT make calls to "UAPush" until AFTER you have invoked

```
[UAirship takeOff:...]
```

This shouldn't be a problem. Firstly, UA shouldn't crash! Secondly, there's plenty of calls to UAPush that make sense before calling takeOff. So far as I can tell, this is undocumented (like most of UA, sadly :( ). i.e. I'd read through the official website and the scant docs multiple times, and never saw mention of this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+iOS%3A+Push, the mostly simplest guide with pictures... Watch for the possible cases you have missed which you shouldn't have.