# Push Notification not working

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I followed this tutorial for push notification.
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services.
In my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions i have called registerForRemoteNotificationTypes.
I have created **SSL** certificate installed in my keychain.
And now trying to send it using **PushMeBaby**.
But I haven't received any push message.

Comment: Try using Urban Airship.

Comment: how to debug? how we can conclude error at server side? I have also tried running simple php script. found at http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12      but no luck

Comment: Have you checked Wheather your app is properly registered for Push Notifications? You can check that at Settings->Notification section.

Comment: yeah it has registered successfully...for the first time only it asked permission.

Comment: Check these links for your server side code 1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052645/apple-pns-push-notification-services-sample-code 2)http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Comment: Are you using the development certificate, or the final release one?  If you are using the development one, you can only use that with a device that you are using for development (ie not an ad-hoc build).  If you are using an ad-hoc distribution, you have to use the release certificate.

Comment: No I am signing with developer profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly the **same code** worked out for iPod. Is it because iPhone was jail-broken????

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed following items ?

1. if you are using Wifi then the port number 2195 and 2196 must be opened.
2. Send the Device token to server or store Device token server for sending push notification.

Check this [Link](http://www.easyapns.com/) , provides all the details with PHP script.

Comment: hi i tested for port using telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195  and i am also able to establish connection using SSL.I referred this http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: Also One more item, Are you using Production or Development certificate , according to that You need to set Sandbox true or false. Check this thing. and check your apple certificate is Push notification enabled.

Comment: its Development certificate even provision-profile used for code signing is developer's profile.