# How to test the Apple Push Notification from iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, apple-push-notifications

In my previous iPhone apps, I didn't use the `Apple Push Notification` function. In my current iPhone app I want to implement Apple Push Notification functionality. I referred the way to implement the APN service in iPhone app,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {  
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {  
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

Can we test the APN service before submitting the app to App store? If it is possible please suggest your ideas to test the app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052645/apple-pns-push-notification-services-sample-code review this will give you all answer about push notification

Comment: The best sample code and answers to your other questions are all to be found on the Apple website. Why not check there first?

Comment: Yes sure you can .. check this [site](http://urbanairship.com/) you can test your app without do any coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send push notifications to your users, it is up to you to store each user's device token in your own database. Then you can address a message to each user, send the message payload to Apple, and Apple will send the message to the user.

I would recommend using [Easy APNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) to accomplish this. It is easy to set up, easy to use, and powerful.