# how to do to receive a push notification when admin publish something new?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webkit

I have a web site made with word-press. I would like to make an app of this web site, it would be a simple web view which will load the web site. The meaning of making an app is because I would like that my users receives push notifications every time a new article is published. Is that posible to do ? I don't want to make a complicated app, just something that send push notifications to the users every time the admin of the web site publish a new article/entry.

Edit to add this link which solved my problem:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181420/i-want-to-send-push-notification-just-after-publish-a-new-post/181422?noredirect=1#comment264953_181422

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement Apple Push Notification Service on ios Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515468/how-can-i-implement-apple-push-notification-service-on-ios-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple different ways to perform what I think you are describing:

Push - http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Fetch - http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/