# Add push notification to my app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app which is already on Apple Store, I need to use the Push Notification, but I have no idea. Do I need to create a new certificate or new app id? Do I need to create a new provisioning profile? Will my app affected if I created those things?

I hope to sort out with you guys.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement Apple Push Notification Service on ios Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515468/how-can-i-implement-apple-push-notification-service-on-ios-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit new version of application with Push Notification service.

Just need to do several update, like

- Goto your Developer centre edit your App ID with Push Notification service.
- Then it automatically ask for configure your push certificate, which you can get from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)
- Goto iTunes connect, create your new version of application. And then finale step
- Submit your app with Xcode or App uploader by changing build/version of your app.

It will not affect your existing application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an existing app id you can follow the below steps to generate certificate with Push notification enabled.

1. In Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, select Identifiers.
2. Under Identifiers, select App IDs.
3. Select the explicit App ID, and click Edit.
4. Scroll down and select the Push Notifications checkbox.
5. Create Certificate under the type of SSL certificate you want to create.
6. You need to generate server side and also the client side certificate with push notification enabled.
7. Use the client side certificate in your app.
8. And for the server side follow the below steps

a)Generate apple push notification certificate and key.ex:-apns-dev-cert.p12, apns-dev-key.p12.

b)Convert the certificate to PEM format:
openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out apns-dev-cert.pem -in apns-dev-cert.p12
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out apns-dev-key.pem -in apns-dev-key.p12
Remove the password with( use this step only for development):                                                                                                                                 openssl rsa -in apns-dev-key.pem -out apns-dev-key-noenc.pem
Combine the key and cert files into apns-dev.pem, which we will use when connecting to APNS with Python:                                                                     cat apns-dev-cert.pem apns-dev-key-noenc.pem > apns-dev.pem

c. Upload apns-dev.pem to your server where you will be sending out push notifications

d. Update APN_APP_ID (Apple app id) and urls in settings

3. Once you have included the certificates and the codes required to support push notification on the client/server side, verify the app and upload it in itunes connect with a new version no.