# Attempting to sent Push Notifications to iOS device - not receiving them

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I have so far done the following:
- Generated certificate and private key as .pem, also cat'd them together.  Successfully connected to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com.
- Using the provisional profile with push notifications is enabled for development, I have a basic app that successfully prompted "Do you want to allow push notifications", so this is working correctly
- Obtained the device token
- I have tried pulling a few pre-made files for SSLing into sandbox from the internet just to see if I can get them running before I start development.

The files are the php file posted here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12.  I actually got a "Message successfully sent"

The python file posted here: [Apple PNS (push notification services) sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052645/apple-pns-push-notification-services-sample-code); I had to edit the Python 3 command "fromhash" line to str(float.fromhash(...))

I also tried using the PyAPNs API: https://github.com/simonwhitaker/PyAPNs.  I still have use_sandbox set to true.

Obviously I changed the device tokens and public keys/certificates to my own.  Sadly I have not received any pushed notifications yet, and I'm not receiving any concrete errors to tell me why.  If anyone can shed some light, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment in radesix's answer, and apologies that I can provide no more detail as it's been a year since I've touched iOS development.

The problem was my provisional profile had the "aps-environment" key set to developer, but for some reason xcode defaulted to "debug". Changing this in the editor solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use a service like urban airship (urbanairship.com) and you'll have this up and running in minutes.  Less for you to maintain in the long run also.

Comment: So far, it hasn't let me create a new app, I keep getting an error page.

Regardless, all I'm trying to do is send a simple message from a script and receive it, or at least find out a reason as to why they're not being received.

Comment: Basically, I've ruled out it being the code at this point.  My device has prompted for push notifications, so my provisional profile checks out.  My certificate/key have successfully connected to the sandbox server via openssl.  So the only thing that could potentially be wrong is maybe I obtained the Device Token in the wrong way?  I'm not sure how that would be possible.

Comment: Are you building out with a developer, ad hoc, or team profile?

Comment: Note that the device tokens are different dependening on developer vs distribution builds

Comment: How can I differentiate which I have then?

Comment: In the preprocessor settings I had DEBUG=1 set for the Debug mode, and printed a message out if DEBUG=1; the message printed, so I seem to be using the developer build.  I assume that's the correct one to use?

Comment: Also ruled out firewalls - we don't block any outgoing connections

Comment: Got it working!  The problem was my provisional profile had the "aps-environment" key set to developer, but for some reason xcode defaulted to "debug".  Changing this in the editor solved my problem.

Comment: @masahane, please post an in depth answer to the problem, not just a comment. Others, like myself, will find this SO post when they encounter this issue. Give back to the community you turn to when you are in need.

Comment: Crazy how you found this over a year later.  Thanks for pointing it out.  That said, having not done any iOS development since this, I won't be able to provide an iota of more detail than what was posted above.