# How possible ANCS ( Apple Notification Center Service ) send phone call or sms to wearable devices?

Tags: ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ancs

As we know ANCS provides the chance to send notification to paired BLE devices such as Pebble alike watches. My question is

Is that possible to send the telephone call info (i.e, the calling number ) or SMS message to the paired BLE devices via ANCS ?

Quite new to ANCS, got a lot sample code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052645/apple-pns-push-notification-services-sample-code) here to verify if the wearable device can know who is calling my iphone, or what message is sending to me. I know Apple has high protection for users, call and sms are high sensitive info, therefore, that will be no way to get such info even from ANCS way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question you have linked to is about APNS - The Push notification service.  ANCS is quite different.  You can receive caller details and so on via ANCS because it requires a pairing process between the phone and the display device - this means that the user is in control of the data - it isn't a random device that is accessing the information

Comment: Sure need pair firstly via BLE 4.0, after that, the device will remember the phone each other. I have ensured that call notification will be sent to watch once phone got called, but not sure if the call number will be sent to watch from the paired phone.

Comment: You can look at what the Pebble watch does - they use ANCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes.

I have been playing with this for a few hours and have configured a 'Central' on my laptop that connects to the ANCS service on my iPhone. I am able to read the 'Notification Source' data and then request the attributes 'Title', 'Subtitle' and 'Message' via the control point characteristic using "Get Notification Attributes". This is as far as I have got...

Have a look at the ANCS specification here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Appendix/Appendix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH3-SW7

Took me a while to understand what was going on but I think the bits you will probably be most interested in are "Get Notification Attributes" or "Get App Attributes".

Comment: Can you post some code, or Approach to achieve same. I am wondering to implement the same thing. Or do you have any resources, links on  the implementational part. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217874/how-pushbullet-sends-all-ios-notification-to-mac