# How Pushbullet sends all iOS Notification to Mac

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, pushbullet, ancs

I was checking different apps that have Mac & iOS communication. I came across cool apps PushBullet and Notifyr. The Most amazing thing I found is showing Push notifications of iOS to their apps in Mac. I tried to search what can be used to achieve this thing, but didn't find anything.

Do have anyone the idea on this, How to share iOs Notifications from iOS Device to the Mac using BLE or any other channel? Is there any Public API or Framework provided by Apple to implement this thing?

Comment: I am looking into that but do you have any tutorial link or some implementation Doc's Link ?