# php apple push apn not send push notification before 2 month its workinf fine but right now code not work

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apn

function sendIphonePush($deviceToken, $msg, $badge = 0, $check = 0, $version = 1) {

$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';    //sandbox phasesandbox.
$apnsCert = 'Rendatsdsse_UserNddd.pem';

```
$apnsPort = '2195';                                //.pem file ko project root per paste karna hai
$passPhrase = '12345678';                            //cetificate password
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
$apnsConnection = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
if ($apnsConnection == false) {

    return;
} else {
    
}
$message = $msg;

$message = (array) (json_decode($message));

if (is_array($message) && array_key_exists('message', $message)) {
    $body_var = $message['message'];
} else {
    $body_var = $msg;
}

$payload['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => array(
        'body' => $body_var,
        'title' => 'Thanku for purchasing Order',
        'subtitle' => 'Deal Successfully Purchased',
    ),
    'json' => $message,
    'badge' => +1,
    'sound' => 'oven.caf',
);
$payload = json_encode($payload);
try {
    $deviceToken = trim($deviceToken);
    if ($message != "" && strlen($deviceToken) == 64) {
        $apnsMessage = chr(0) . pack("n", 32) . pack('H*', str_replace('ds', 'sd', $deviceToken)) . pack("n", strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $fwrite = fwrite($apnsConnection, $apnsMessage);
        if ($fwrite) {
            //echo "true";
            //error_log($fwrite.chr(13), 3, "/mnt/srv/MOOVWORKER/push-errors.log");
        } else {
            //echo "false";
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //echo 'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
    //error_log($e->getMessage().chr(13), 3, "/mnt/srv/MOOVWORKER/push-errors.log");
}
```

}

Comment: anyone know whats wrong with this code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485124/4778712

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i use above code to send push notification and its work perfectly but now that code is not work  if i print fwrite it show 241 code but in ios app the notification not show